# GPUImagePicture with GPUImageView target?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I'm trying to send the output of `GPUImagePicture` to a `GPUImageView`,

This is more or less my code:

```
GPUImageView *backgroundImageView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo"]; //The image is not nil
GPUImagePicture *imageInput = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image];

[imageInput addTarget:backgroundImageView];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundImageView];
```

The problem is that the backgroundImageView doesn't seem to be rendering the image... what could be going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you've set up your filter (or display) chain, you need

```
[imageInput processImage];
```

to propagate the image down the filter chain and get it to display.

Comment: What if you don't have a filter but want to just "pass" the image through to the GPUImageView instance?

Comment: @NicoHämäläinen - Same. Targeting the GPUImagePicture instance to the GPUImageView will allow it to be displayed, but you need to use `-processImage` for the image to propagate down the chain to make it to the view.